# Changing the font spacing in figure/table captions

Tags: captions, line-spacing

I am writing a thesis.  Both the body of the text and my figure/table captions are double-spaced.  However, I need my captions to be single-spaced.  I tried resetting the spacing on the captions using `\captionsetup`, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I am including sample code below.

```
%  thesis.tex  2014-08-08  Mark Senn
%
%  This is the root file for a simple example thesis.
%  This example can also be used to prepare a dissertation.

% See
%     http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/#Options
% for documentclass options.
% CHANGE NEXT LINE?
\documentclass[me,thesis]{puthesis}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure}

% Force LaTeX not to hyphenate words that have less than three letters on each side of the hyphen.  
\lefthyphenmin4
\righthyphenmin4

% For multi-row cells and broken lines in tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{caption}

% Captions generally show both a period and a colon.  This suppresses the colon and leaves only the period.  
\captionsetup{labelsep=none}

% Try getting the captions to be single spaced.  
\captionsetup[table]{font=singlespacing}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=singlespacing}

% For forcing figure placement where necessary
\usepackage{float}

% Automatically wrap around text when using "verbatim" environment.
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    columns=flexible,
    breaklines=true
}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{capt-of}

% Title of thesis (used on cover and in abstract).
% Use \title{Put Title Here} for a one-line title.
% Use \\ to separate lines in multi-line titles.
% Put % at the end of the last line of a title
% to avoid getting an extra space in the abstract.

\title{%
  An Example Thesis Done with LaTeX\\ 
  That Has a Long Title%
}

% First author name with first name first is used for cover.
% Second author name with last name first is used for abstract.
% Your full name as it appears in the University records appears
% on the cover.
% There are two forms of author, with and without initials.
% There are examples of both below.
\author{Ivan S. Bogdanovich}{Bogdanovich, Ivan S.}

% First is long title of degree (used on cover).
% Second is abbreviation for degree (used in abstract).
% Third is the month the degree was (will be) awarded (used on cover
% and in abstract).
% Last is the year the degree was (wlll be) awarded (used on cover
% and in abstract).
\pudegree{Master of Science and Mechanical Engineering}{MSME}{July}{2014}

% Major professor (used in abstract).
\majorprof{Heinrich von Weltschmerz}

% Campus (used only on cover)
\campus{Fort Wayne}

% My command definitions specific to my thesis.

% Let typing "\en" be exactly the same as typing "\ensuremath". 
\let\en=\ensuremath

% Set things up so \margins will show where the margins on the page are.
\newcommand{\margins}{\Repeat{Show where the margins for the page are.}{4}}

% Define a \ve command with two arguments, so if it called with
%     \ve an
% it will expand to
%     {\en{a_1},~\en{a_2},\ \ldots,~\en{a_{n}}}
\newcommand{\ve}[2]{\en{#1_1},~\en{#1_2},\ \ldots,~\en{#1_{#2}}}


% To LaTeX only some parts of your thesis put the
% names of the parts to include here.  For example,
% \includeonly{front} would only process front.tex.
% \includeonly{front,introduction} would only process
% front.tex and introduction.tex.
% To print the final copy of your thesis put a '%'
% in front of the \includeonly command and run LaTeX
% three times to make sure that all cross-references
% are correct.  Then run BibTeX once and LaTeX twice
% more.
% CHANGE NEXT LINE?
%\includeonly{front,introduction}

\begin{document}

% Start a new volume for your thesis.
% All theses must have at least one volume.
% If your thesis has multiple volumes put another "\volume"
% command between chapters below.
\volume

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  This is a sample paragraph.  

Sample table below.

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a sample table caption.  This is a sample table caption.  This is a sample table caption.  This is a sample table caption.  This is a sample table caption.  This is a sample table caption.}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c}
        \hline
        & \bf 1 & \bf 2 & \bf 3 & 4 \\
        \hline
        \bf 5 & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{Tab1}
\end{table}

Sample figure below.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a sample figure caption.  This is a sample figure caption.  This is a sample figure caption.  This is a sample figure caption.  This is a sample figure caption.  This is a sample figure caption.}
    \label{Fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic but possibly of some relevance anyway: You have the following comment in your preamble: "Force LaTeX not to hyphenate words that have [fewer] than three letters on each side of the hyphen." If that's the objective, the instructions should be `\lefthyphenmin3` and `\righthyphenmin3`, respectively.

Comment: I tried changing it just in case.  No effect.

Comment: "No effect" is rather unspecific. Please provide a bit more detail.

Comment: It doesn't change the look of the tables at all.  I may have just forgotten to update my comment.

Comment: Note that I prefaced my comment with "Off-topic but..." It was thus certainly not intended to address the spacing issues. What I did want to achieve is to point out that if the comment about hyphenation limits is meant to be taken seriously, you must adjust the values of `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin`. OTOH, if you are happy with `\lefthyphenmin4` and `\righthyphenmin4`, you should update the comment.

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 4):

The [`puthesis` class](http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/#Options) completely redefines the way the captions work. While adding the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) to the preamble solves the problem, other issues arise.

My suggestion is to define the `\@makecaption` macro to suit your needs and provide a consistent float caption. By adding

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1 #2}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\reset@font
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1 #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble you have the same caption for both tables and figures. The above definition (apart from the resetting of `\baselinestretch`) was taken directly from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls), the base class of `puthesis`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This does fix the spacing of the captions.  However, it also shrinks the row size on many (not all) of the tables.  How do I keep the tables themselves from messing up?

Comment: @Daniel: Can you provide a minimal example replicating this problem?

Comment: If I put \usepackage{setspace} in the code above, just under "subfigure", the rows in the sample table shrink.

Comment: @Daniel: When I remove all the settings related to the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) that you've used I get the appropriate single-spaced `\caption` for both `figure` and `table`. See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/PteV3Qyi).

Comment: I noticed that when I remove \caption entirely, the table caption number (i.e. "Table #.#" pops up to the line above the rest of the caption.  Also, if I shorten the table caption so that it is less than one line long, it is not centered.  Is there a way to keep the caption number from popping up, and to keep the caption centered if it is less than one line?

Comment: @Daniel: If this is a thesis template, shouldn't you stick to the default formatting?

Comment: @Daniel: See my updated answer which produces the expected output.

Comment: My adviser said I could dispense with the centered formatting.  So I think this problem is solved.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Since `puthesis` has its very own `\@makecaption` code I think own `\@makecaption` code should be based on the one offered by `puthesis`, and not based on the one offered by `report`.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: The difference between the two are quite substantial in the sense that `puthesis` sets a figure caption differently from that of a table caption. The OP seemed to request something that provides consistency between the two, which `report` offered, without the conditional trickery in `puthesis`.

Comment: From the website: "It is a LaTeX typesetting system documentclass used to format Purdue Master's bypass reports, Master's theses, PhD dissertations, and PhD preliminary reports." So the Purdue University wants it this way, so why using their document class and not following their design rules? This does not sound like a good idea to me, but this doubting is addressed to Daniel, of course.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Yes, [I mentioned this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276261/changing-the-font-spacing-in-figure-table-captions/276263?noredirect=1#comment665044_276263)...

Comment: @Werner: Upps, I forgot to click "show 5 more comments", so I didn't read this. Shame on me.